# SQL - Получить усредненные значения за час

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица содержащая значения температуры и времени, когда это значение было получено:

CREATE TABLE Termo_Statistics(
Time DATETIME NOT NULL,
Temperature int NOT NULL);

Содержит значения :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос должен выдать данные в виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. усредненные значения температуры в границах одного часа в одном столбце и начало данного часа во втором столбце.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`Time`,'%Y.%m.%d %h.00'),
  Sum(`Temperature`)/Count(`Temperature`)
From 
  Termo_Statistics
Group by
  DATE_FORMAT(`Time`,'%Y%m%d%h');
```

Comment: В SQL Server нет функции DATE_FORMAT. Это из MySQL

Comment: Переписал для MS SQL с Использованием "CONVERT" получилось:                    
                                                                                                                                      
 `SELECT 
   CONVERT(varchar(13), Time, 120),
  Sum(Temperature)/Count(Temperature)
From 
  Termo_Statistics
Group by
   CONVERT(varchar(13), Time, 120);`

Comment: @Alexandr61region1 Ну ещё `SUM()/COUNT()` замените на `AVG()`...

Comment: есть же `avg()`, зачем `sum() / count()`?

Comment: Итого вышло :`SELECT 
   CONVERT(varchar(13), Time, 120) as Time,
  AVG(Temperature) as Temperature
From 
  Termo_Statistics
Group by
   CONVERT(varchar(13), Time, 120);`

Comment: Правда значения получаются усеченные - т.е. не "2018-10-22 17.00" а  
 "2018-10-22 17"

Comment: @Alexandr61region1 *Правда значения получаются усеченные* ну добавьте нули вручную: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(13), Time, 120) + ':00'`, какие сложности-то?

Comment: @Akina, костыль какой то получается(  Ну ок.. делать нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так, под Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(TS.DATETIME, 'HH24') AS DATETIME,
                AVG(TS.TEMPERATURE) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(TS.DATETIME, 'HH24')) AS TEMPERATURE
  FROM TERMO_STATISTICS TS
  ORDER BY DATETIME;
```

под MS SQL Server:

думаю должно работать))

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR, TS.DATETIME, 120) AS DATETIME) AS DATETIME,
                AVG(TS.TEMPERATURE) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(CONVERT(CHAR, TS.DATETIME, 120) AS DATETIME)) AS TEMPERATURE
  FROM TERMO_STATISTICS TS
  ORDER BY DATETIME;
```

Comment: В Microsoft SQL функции  TRUNC вроде нет

Comment: Это под Oracle, вместо trunc можно воспользоватся функциями cast и convert