# Суммирование полей по суткам

Tags: sql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, sDateTime), 0) AS DATE) xDay, 
       AVG(F_307_PV) F_307_PV,
       AVG(Power_Water_Garaj) Power_Water_Garaj
  FROM Main
 WHERE (sDateTime BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-25') 
   AND F_307_PV IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, sDateTime), 0)
 ORDER BY xDay
```

который дает такой результат:

```
1.  2019-03-01  26,7152467171351    96,6716488838196
2.  2019-03-01  26,6891029569838    99,2964409298367
3.  2019-03-01  26,6758314573665    98,0521158946258
4.  2019-03-01  26,649173980289     104,37670680152
5.  2019-03-01  26,5915962590112    114,679965718587
6.  2019-03-01  26,5916170941459    108,178197436863
7.  2019-03-01  26,5843454748807    101,530929831077
8.  2019-03-01  26,5647275686264    95,4381384319729
9.  2019-03-01  26,5544141663445    101,707038021088
10. 2019-03-01  26,5975976811515    101,944240315755
11. 2019-03-01  26,6753537204531    91,7267462094625
12. 2019-03-01  26,6685935364829    101,893471887377
13. 2019-03-01  26,7164451652103    97,4600526809692
14. 2019-03-01  26,6822000450558    102,358738782671
15. 2019-03-01  26,6285459280014    112,600410599179
16. 2019-03-01  26,6008875608444    111,43766424391
17. 2019-03-01  26,5666720231374    117,918136776818
18. 2019-03-01  26,5007328463198    117,245253126545
19. 2019-03-01  26,3703450361888    125,036452198029
20. 2019-03-01  26,5134925550885    114,726272116767
21. 2019-03-01  26,5193503777186    109,408451747894
22. 2019-03-01  26,395676456122     120,732144549697
23. 2019-03-01  26,1437028514014    121,879121769799
24. 2019-03-01  26,2547079748578    117,592820983463
25. 2019-03-02  26,0438704702589    122,186901262071
26. 2019-03-02  26,1653890715705    127,798842546675
27. 2019-03-02  26,2762022468779    126,469414393107
28. 2019-03-02  26,3626771476534    130,725670909882
29. 2019-03-02  26,3797778897299    129,247850954699
30. 2019-03-02  26,4265042861303    135,095087125566
31. 2019-03-02  26,4931580464045    141,665470684899
32. 2019-03-02  26,3914508899053    126,884803496467
...
```

Мне нужно получить сумму средних почасовых значений за сутки.

Comment: а СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: @Viktorov SQL Server

Comment: `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/896241/261244` можете здесь взгянуть